# Remove Optional Alamofire (and anywhere)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to implement a new REST service in Swift but i'm lost. I need remove "Optional" string in my service receeipt:

```
func callServiceReceives(){

    var jsonReceived: JSON = []

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8080/userServicesProvider")
        .responseJSON { (_, _, pruebaJSON, _) in

            jsonReceived = JSON(pruebaJSON!)
            println(jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count) // "Optional(4)"
    }

}

//  If i try if let temp:String! = String(stringInterpolationSegment: jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count) {
//  println(temp) -> "Optional(4)"
//  } -> say me "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

//If i try ->     let temp:String! = String(stringInterpolationSegment: jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count)
//
//                if let temp2 = temp!{
//                    println(temp2) -> "Optional(4)"
//} -> i had the same problem: "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your `!` in the wrong place. It should be here:

```
println(jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count!)
```

For safety's sake, though, you might be better off with:

```
println(jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count.map{String($0)} ?? "Error")
```

Which will print "Error" if your array is nil, or:

```
jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count.map(println)
```

Won't print anything if your array is nil.

Comment: The count is not an optional, sorry if i’m wrong but wouldn’t you need to replace the `?` behind the array with a `!`? You will need to force unwrap the array, not the count

Comment: Kind of - both would actually work. If you do `someOptional?.someProperty` what you get back is actually an optional, because of the chaining. So `someOptional?.someProperty!` and `someOptional!.someProperty` are equivalent, but obviously the second one is preferable. The reason I used the first one in my answer was just to show the optional chaining, to then get you to `jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count.map(println)` which I think is the best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was lost but with your help i did it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a optional because your array is optional.

Try printing `println(jsonReceived[“recipes”].array!.count)`

This however isn’t the best way to do it. You should use an `if let` statement to check if your array is not nil. After that you can get the count of the new let. This won’t be an optional anymore.

```
if let temp = jsonReceived[“recipes”].array{
    println(temp.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know if there's a difference between an empty array and no array at all....

`let count = jsonReceived["recibos"].array?.count as? Int ?? 0`